# Getting conflict error with the connection string in machine.config and app.config files

Tags: asp.net, .net

In my machine.config file I have a connection string as follows:

```
    <connectionStrings><add name="sqlAppConn" connectionString="Data Source=CTDISP-SVN;Initial Catalog=netlic;User ID=admina;Password=password1;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

I created a c# console application which also uses a connection string with the same name in its App.config file, but its pointing to a different database. The connection string in there is:

```
    <connectionStrings><add name="sqlAppConn" connectionString="Data Source=CTDISP-SVN;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;User ID=adminb;Password=password2;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

When I run the program I get an error saying that there is a conflict with the connection strings.  But I thought it would be fine because it will overwrite the connection string in my machine.config file.
However I am still getting the error? why?...

Comment: What specifically is the error? Have you noticed that you're not just declaring connection strings but actually *adding* them? If you add something and it's already there, probably not going to be happy. Perhaps you should remove it if it exists, then add it in your app.config?

Comment: how would I remove it if it already exists in machine.config? I thought if i have it in app.config it will overwrite it.

Comment: According to the site 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files

Connection strings can be stored as key/value pairs in the connectionStrings section of the configuration element of an application configuration file. Child elements include add, clear, and remove

Perhaps putting "<clear />" in your app config before the add entry would do the trick?

Comment: Yes. thank you. adding <clear/> did the trick!

Comment: Glad it helped. Posted the info as an answer for anyone else that may come across it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the site

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files

> Connection strings can be stored as key/value pairs in the connectionStrings section of the configuration element of an application configuration file. Child elements include add, clear, and remove.

Putting `<clear />` in your app config before the add entry should do the trick.